# Class hierarchy Loop - High Level Design Suggestions

Tags: c++, oop

I need a little assistance with high level design of this program.

I am manually creating class objects based on an XML description. It has nodes which define settings of a piece of hardware. The trouble is the nodes in the XML can simply point to other nodes by name. To be able to find the address of these node objects quickly based on name, I am using a map. This is simplified view:

```
class XMLfile
{
    public:
        Node* GetNode(const string FeatName);   //Searches through "nodes" map to get pointer to     Node
    private:
         map<std::string, Node*> nodes;
};
```

Then I define nodes as follows:

```
class Node
{
    public:
        virtual int GetValue();
        virtual int Load(XML_type);
};
```

Then depending on the exact "type" of node, I create a few derived classes with additional variables.

```
class Integer: public Node
{
    int IntegerSpecificVar;
    int GetValue();
    int Load(XML_type);
    private:    
       int Value;
       string p_Value;
};
```

The XML can be one of the two:

```
<Value>5</value>    Which my object load will load 5 into int Value.
or
<p_Value>NodeName</p_Value>  Which my object loader will load the string into p_Value.
```

Depending on the object in the XML, the GetValue() returns the int Value, or a pointer to a string with a different nodename. If its a pointer, I need to get the pointer to that node and then call GetValue on that object. What I really want to do is call XML::GetNode(nodename") but this is out of context.

One idea to get my Node objects access to that map is to create the class Node which is derived from the XMLfile:

```
class Node: public XMLfile
```

then I get circular references since it has not loaded yet. If I switch the order between class Node and class XMLfile, then XMLfile doesn't know what a Node class/type is. Note this is all in one big file for now.

IF anyone can offer general suggestions how to better arrange this it would be appreciated.

Comment: How about putting an XMLFile pointer inside your Node?

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to think of a `Node` as an specified case of `XMLfile`, so don't derive one from the other. Inheritance means the relationship of **A 'is-a' B**.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and possibly dirty solutions:

1. make the map a parameter of `GetValue`, or
2. store a (const) reference or pointer to the map inside `Node`.

Comment: I understand both of these solutions. But what would be a more proper architectural solution?